# prevent multiple login : Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, security, session, customer-session

I want to prevent a customer to login multiple times from different machines. When a customer tries to login I want to logout customer logout from all other machines.

How can I logout customer from all previous machines?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case it makes sense to adjust the **session validation settings** and enable the following:

- Validate REMOTE_ADDR > set to Yes
- Validate HTTP_VIA > set to Yes
- Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR > set to Yes

Note that depending on the internet connection/proxy settings of your customers/guests one of those three fields can be set/changed. It might need some finetuning.

Note that this will also affect session validation settings for not logged in users: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/security-session-validation.html

Furthermore there are some cool customer password options: The **number of times** a customer can try to enter a password, the **number of minutes between attempts**, the **number of total attempts** before the account is locked, and the **length of the lockout** can be set in the password configuration section.

See also: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/password-options.html